# Javascript array destructuring assignment gives strange errors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I've just noticed a strange error when using Javascript destructuring assignment, which took me some guesswork to resolve.  I'm posting here so I can show what I learned.  (I accept that the question about Javascript semicolon insertion is answered by [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi), but my problem was about how to diagnose a strange error when ASI works differently than I was expecting; it's an answer that I would have hoped to find when searching for "array destructuring error" or similar.)

The following code:

```
let next_col_time_step = head_steps.reduce(
    choose_next_step, [-1, -1, null]
    )
[next_step_col, next_step_time, next_step] = next_col_time_step
```

When run generates an very confusing error:

```
ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'next_col_time_step' before initialization
```

Despite (apparently) having been just initialized before the error line.

Or, if I try to see what value has been assigned, thus:

```
let next_col_time_step = head_steps.reduce(
    choose_next_step, [-1, -1, null]
    )
console.log("next_col_time_step %s", next_col_time_step)
[next_step_col, next_step_time, next_step] = next_col_time_step
```

I see the expected value displayed and a different error:

```
next_col_time_step 2,52,[object Object] 
TypeError: console.log(...) is undefined
```

I.e., `console.log(...)` apparently works as expected, then is reported as undefined.  What's going on here?

Comment: read your code like the JS interpreter would read it: `let next_col_time_step = (head_steps.reduce(choose_next_step, [-1, -1, null])[next_step] = next_col_time_step);`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I accept that the question about Javascript semicolon insertion is answered elsewhere, hence is a relevant reference, but my problem was about how to diagnose a strange error when ASI worked differently than I was expecting.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74080/close-as-duplicate-what-if-only-the-answer-is-a-duplicate

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a confusing ambiguity in Javascript syntax.

Notice that I wasn't using `;` statement terminators?

It appears that the array destructuring assignment is being parsed as an array indexing operation applied to the previous statement.

Quick fix: add `;` after the preceding statement (though this unfortunately forces an inconsistent style if these are generally omitted):

```
let next_col_time_step = head_steps.reduce(
    choose_next_step, [-1, -1, null]
    );
[next_step_col, next_step_time, next_step] = next_col_time_step
```

And, *voila!*, all is well :)

Comment: One of the many reasons why it's good style to always use semicolons .

Comment: @chris p bacon:  Yeah, I guess.  I used to use semicolons until quite recently, but started switching because it seemed a common style not to do so in some recent ES6 code I was working with.